# url rewrite based on login user

Tags: php

hi is it possible to make url rewrite based on login user?

For example if user **basikal** login, they will see the url at the address bar as http://localhost/test/basikal/index.php.

Meanwhile the actual address is http://localhost/real/index.php

I need this because i got user that want the system customize to their profile but i dont want to create multiple copies because it is troublesome to maintain it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this; a solid MVC framework will allow you to set custom routes.

But simply:

- Create a rewrite rule that rewrites `/app/(.+)?/` to `/app/`.
- On every page view, in php, check the url. If it isn't `/app/username`, redirect user to `/app/username/`
- Do not ever use the username in the url for identification purposes, always use the session.

This will give the impression to the user that they have a personalized url.

This is neither efficient, nor pretty but it will work.